# What are the best job combinations?

Tags: bravely-default

I am wondering what are the best job combinations in Bravely Default. Is there any point to upgrade melee jobs for casters for example? And do I even have to switch the jobs i.e. strive for combinations or stick with one job?

Comment: Something from [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/729328-bravely-default/68211148) I suppose

Comment: There are many combinations that work well together. A common one is a dual wielding Dark Knight with Gloom. As you may have noticed, JP required to level up is pretty linear until 8 when it takes a huge jump. I usually got to 8 or so then switched and saved maxing jobs for late game when you get tons of JP per battle.

Comment: More often than not I found it unadvantageous to switch jobs because of that stat (and dps as consequence) drop, so I thought that sticking to few builds might help

Comment: @VladimirBeletskiy that's true, and I highly recommend you don't switch jobs right before a boss fight :) Still, you can switch jobs, put the battles to auto for a few encounters, and then your characters should be back up to speed. You may want to backtrack to easier enemies if you switch more than one character at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely not the only working combination and probably isn't the best but I've found it to work in almost any situation.

- Tiz as Ranger with Ninja.
- Angés as White Mage with any subclass.
- Ringabel as Dark Knight with Time Mage.
- Edea as Sword Master with Spell Fencer.

  1. Have everyone Default on the first turn.
  2. Have Tiz use Kairai on Edea.
  3. Have Angés heal Edea when necessary. Otherwise, summon or attack.
  4. Have Ringabel use Black Bane until 10% HP. Then use Minus Strike.
  5. If Edea does not have an active sword spell, cast one that is super effective against your foe(I recommend using Drain). Then use Nothing Ventured if against multiple foes, Know Thine Enemy if against one.
  6. Repeat until dead.